# Join three tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
User
uid name

Roles
uid role_id

Subscriptions
uid subscriptions_id
```

Ok, this may seem too easy, but we all failed to get the wished result, which should look like this:

```
user roles subscriptions
1    2,3   1,4,5
2    2,4   4,5,6
....
```

Instead, the result looks like this:

```
user roles subscriptions
1    2,3   5
2    2,4   6
....
```

The select command looks like this:

```
SELECT User.name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(Roles.role_id), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(Subscriptions.subscriptions_id) 
FROM   User 
       LEFT JOIN Roles ON User.uid = Roles.uid 
       LEFT JOIN Subscriptions ON Users.uid = Subscriptions.uid
```

btw - the GROUP_CONCAT is not the problem. If I leave that out, I still get something like this:

```
user roles subscriptions
1    2     5
1    3     5
2    2     6
```

instead of

```
user roles subscriptions
1    2     1
1    3     4
1    -     5
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
SELECT User.uid, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Roles.role_id), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Subscriptions.subscriptions_id)
FROM   User 
       LEFT JOIN Roles ON User.uid = Roles.uid 
       LEFT JOIN Subscriptions ON User.uid = Subscriptions.uid
GROUP BY User.uid
```

and I got this:

```
user    roles    subscriptions
1       2,3      1,5,4
2       2,4      4,5,6
```

Is that youe result?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
 u.uid, u.name, r.roles_grp_concat, s.subs_grp_concat
from
 users u
left outer join
(
   select uid, group_concat(role_id) as roles_grp_concat
   from roles group by uid
) r on r.uid = u.uid
left outer join
(
   select uid, group_concat(subscriptions_id) as subs_grp_concat
   from subscriptions group by uid
) s on s.uid = u.uid
order by
 u.uid;
```